# Zsh - export: not valid in this context: charge"}'

Tags: docker, environment-variables, zsh, cat

I have .env file with value as

```
export AB_EXPERIMENT_NAMES='{"consumer_estimated_delivery_charges_v1":"Delivery charge"}'
```

but when I run it like below I am getting the error

```
export: not valid in this context: charge\"}\"'
```

```
export $(cat .env | xargs -0)
```

The issue seems to be in the space in `Delivery charge`.
How can I resolve this.

Comment: Why are you using `xargs`? As long as `.env` contains valid shell assignments (which is *not* a safe assumption, by the way), you can simply source it. `. .env`.

Comment: I am using it in the dockerfile 
`RUN cd ${APP_DIR} && \
   export $(cat .env | xargs -0) && \
    mix local.hex --force && \
    mix local.rebar --force`

Comment: @SahilPaudel, That context should have been in your original problem statement. But it still doesn't explain why you're using the obfuscated `export $(cat .env | xargs -0)`. Which, in addition to not doing anything useful, involves a "useless use of cat." Have you actually run just the `cat .env | xargs -0` and inspected the output? Hint: `export export AB_EXPERIMENT_NAMES...` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @SahilPaude, Another hint: in an interactive zsh session run `set -x` then `export "$(cat .env | xargs -0)"`. Note the double-quotes around the command substitution to inhibit word splitting of its output.

Comment: @SahilPaudel: Your command is equivalent to `export $(xargs -0 /bin/echo <.env)`, so to see the effect, I sugget you do a plain `xargs -0 /bin/echo <.env` to observe what is happening. You will see immediately, why your approach does not work. The question is why do you want to set the environment in such an unusual way? Is this kind of a programming challenge?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of doing `export $(cat .env | xargs -0)`, you should just do

```
source .env
```

But for the sake of it, let's say that you actually want to read the export statements from `.env` and then pass them as arguments to another command, but without the word `export` in front of them. The right way to do it in Zsh would be:

```
<command> ${${(f)"$( < .env )"}[@]#export }
```

This works as follows:

- `< .env` reads the contents of `.env` and passes them to standard input. If there's no command connected to `<` (as is the case here), then Zsh will implicitly use `cat`.
- `$( < .env )` captures the output of `< .env` and expands it to a string. Note that using `$( < ... )` is faster than using `$( cat ... )`, because Zsh does not actually spawn a separate process for it.
- `"$( < .env )"` ensures each chunk of whitespace, including each line break, is preserved, instead of each being converted to a single space.
- `${(f)...}` splits the string on newlines.
- `${...[@]#export }` removes `export`  from the beginning of each array element.

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html for more info.